# Compiling restbed via cmake FetchContent (openssl errs DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0)?

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, openssl, restbed

I have this setup on Raspbian Stretch:

```
pi@raspberry:~/rtest $ tree /home/pi/rtest/
/home/pi/rtest/
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp

1 directory, 2 files
pi@raspberry:~/rtest $ g++ --version | head -1
g++ (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
```

The files are these: `CMakeLists.txt` (the `set(restbed_BUILD_SSL OFF)` is my guess based on [trouble running the https example · Issue #470 · Corvusoft/restbed](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/issues/470)  and https://discourse.cmake.org/t/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-options-of-a-project-before-fetch-content/268):

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)
include(FetchContent)


FetchContent_Declare(
  restbed
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed
  GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
  GIT_TAG        0c99284 # Oct 3, 2022, latest in Jan 2024
)
set(restbed_BUILD_SSL OFF)
set(restbed_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(restbed)

project(rtest C CXX ASM)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources
  main.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${restbed_SOURCE_DIR}/source
)
```

... and `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <restbed>

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

Then I do this:

```
pi@raspberry:~/rtest $ cd ~/rtest/build
pi@raspberry:~/rtest/build $ ~/src/cmake-3.28.1/bin/cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-- Populating restbed
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-subbuild
[ 11%] Creating directories for 'restbed-populate'
[ 22%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'restbed-populate'
Cloning into 'restbed-src'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 14304, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (239/239), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (131/131), done.
remote: Total 14304 (delta 111), reused 186 (delta 86), pack-reused 14065
Receiving objects: 100% (14304/14304), 4.00 MiB | 5.48 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9161/9161), done.
HEAD is now at 0c99284... Merge pull request #517 from voldien/asio-target-include
Submodule 'dependency/asio' (https://github.com/corvusoft/asio-dependency) registered for path 'dependency/asio'
Submodule 'dependency/catch' (https://github.com/corvusoft/catch-dependency) registered for path 'dependency/catch'
Submodule 'dependency/openssl' (https://github.com/corvusoft/openssl-dependency) registered for path 'dependency/openssl'
Cloning into '/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio'...
Cloning into '/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/catch'...
Cloning into '/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl'...
Submodule path 'dependency/asio': checked out 'a4d820dd69b37fb8daee275d20eb162054453414'
Submodule path 'dependency/catch': checked out 'd10b9bd02e098476670f5eb0527d2c7281476e8a'
Submodule path 'dependency/openssl': checked out 'fd78df59b0f656aefe96e39533130454aa957c00'
Submodule 'boringssl' (https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl) registered for path 'dependency/openssl/boringssl'
Submodule 'krb5' (https://github.com/krb5/krb5) registered for path 'dependency/openssl/krb5'
Submodule 'pyca.cryptography' (https://github.com/pyca/cryptography.git) registered for path 'dependency/openssl/pyca-cryptography'
Cloning into '/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/boringssl'...
Cloning into '/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/krb5'...
Cloning into '/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/pyca-cryptography'...
Submodule path 'dependency/openssl/boringssl': checked out '2070f8ad9151dc8f3a73bffaa146b5e6937a583f'
Submodule path 'dependency/openssl/krb5': checked out '890ca2f401924cdcb88f493950b04700bbe52db3'
Submodule path 'dependency/openssl/pyca-cryptography': checked out '09403100de2f6f1cdd0d484dcb8e620f1c335c8f'
[ 33%] Performing update step for 'restbed-populate'
[ 44%] No patch step for 'restbed-populate'
[ 55%] No configure step for 'restbed-populate'
[ 66%] No build step for 'restbed-populate'
[ 77%] No install step for 'restbed-populate'
[ 88%] No test step for 'restbed-populate'
[100%] Completed 'restbed-populate'
[100%] Built target restbed-populate
CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/restbed-src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

##############################################################
#                                                            #
#  Copyright 2013-2020, Corvusoft Ltd, All Rights Reserved.  #
#                                                            #
#  Restbed is dual-licensed requiring commerical entities    #
#  to acquire a Corvusoft Permissive License, Contact        #
#  sales@corvusoft.co.uk for details.                        #
#                                                            #
##############################################################

-- Found ASIO include at: /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include
-- Found OpenSSL include at: /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include
-- Found OpenSSL library at: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.a
-- Found OpenSSL library at: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so
-- Found Crypto library at: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.a
-- Found Crypto library at: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so
-- Found catch: /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/catch/single_include/catch2
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/restbed-src/test/unit/CMakeLists.txt:3 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/restbed-src/test/feature/CMakeLists.txt:3 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/restbed-src/test/regression/CMakeLists.txt:3 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/restbed-src/test/integration/CMakeLists.txt:3 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Configuring done (280.8s)
-- Generating done (1.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/rtest/build
```

So, the FetchContent pulled openssl and its dependencies, and in spite of warnings, the `cmake` step completes.

Now, if I run `make`:

```
pi@raspberry:~/rtest/build $ make
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rtest.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/restbed:2:0,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/main.cpp:1:
/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/corvusoft/restbed/http.hpp:109:44: warning: ‘Http’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             Http( const Http& original ) = delete;
                                            ^~~~~~
/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/corvusoft/restbed/http.hpp:118:53: warning: ‘Http’ is deprecated: HTTP client is deprecated; we will release a complimentary client framework at a future date. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             Http& operator =( const Http& value ) = delete;
                                                     ^~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/restbed:2:0,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/main.cpp:1:
/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/corvusoft/restbed/http.hpp:46:131: note: declared here
 PRECATED("HTTP client is deprecated; we will release a complimentary client framework at a future date.") HTTP_EXPORT Http
                                                                                                                       ^~~~
In file included from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/restbed:2:0,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/main.cpp:1:
/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/corvusoft/restbed/http.hpp:118:53: warning: ‘Http’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             Http& operator =( const Http& value ) = delete;
                                                     ^~~~~~
[  1%] Linking CXX executable rtest
[  1%] Built target rtest
[  2%] Building CXX object _deps/restbed-build/CMakeFiles/restbed-static.dir/source/corvusoft/restbed/detail/http_impl.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/x509.h:22:0,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:20,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_types.hpp:24,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl/context_base.hpp:19,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl/context.hpp:23,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl.hpp:18,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/corvusoft/restbed/detail/socket_impl.hpp:29,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/corvusoft/restbed/detail/http_impl.cpp:21:
/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/ec.h:274:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0’
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0(int EC_GROUP_get_curve_GFp(const EC_GROUP *group, BIGNUM *p,
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/ec.h:543:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0’
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0(int EC_POINT_get_affine_coordinates_GFp(const EC_GROUP *group,
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/ec.h:585:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0’
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0(int EC_POINT_set_affine_coordinates_GF2m(const EC_GROUP *group,
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/x509.h:26:0,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:20,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_types.hpp:24,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl/context_base.hpp:19,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl/context.hpp:23,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/ssl.hpp:18,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/corvusoft/restbed/detail/socket_impl.hpp:29,
                 from /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/source/corvusoft/restbed/detail/http_impl.cpp:21:
/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/dsa.h:103:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘int’
 int DSA_sign(int type, const unsigned char *dgst, int dlen,
 ^~~
_deps/restbed-build/CMakeFiles/restbed-static.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target '_deps/restbed-build/CMakeFiles/restbed-static.dir/source/corvusoft/restbed/detail/http_impl.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [_deps/restbed-build/CMakeFiles/restbed-static.dir/source/corvusoft/restbed/detail/http_impl.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:422: recipe for target '_deps/restbed-build/CMakeFiles/restbed-static.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [_deps/restbed-build/CMakeFiles/restbed-static.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:135: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So, in spite of warnings, my executable compiles - but then, the build process wants to build `_deps/restbed-build/CMakeFiles/restbed-static.dir/source/corvusoft/restbed/detail/http_impl.cpp.o` (probably to build a library?), and there it crashes with `error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0’`.

I have seen [DEPRECATEDIN_1_2_0() is too eager · Issue #6814 · openssl/openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6814), but I really cannot tell what I can/should do to get rid of the error.

I thought, the easiest would be just to compile without SSL - but then this `restbed/detail/http_impl.cpp.o` explicitly includes SSL stuff, even if the name "**http**_impl" implies no SSL? So I'm not sure whether my `set(restbed_BUILD_SSL OFF)` would have an effect there ...

So what can I do from CMake to get restbed and/or openssl to compile in this case? I could live without https (the openssl part) for now, but I really cannot tell how could I specify that in CMakeLists.txt ...

Comment: The line `set(restbed_BUILD_SSL OFF)` is wrong: The option of restbed project is named `BUILD_SSL` (without `restbed` prefix), and for set an option for a project, included via FetchContent, one should use CACHE keyword: `set(BUILD_SSL OFF CACHE BOOL "Disable building of SSL in restbed project)`. The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62101576/using-fetchcontent-declare-together-with-cmake-args) provides more details about setting parameters for a project, included via FetchContent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got something - somewhat surprisingly for me, all I needed to do was to set the CMake variables intended for `restbed` on my main `cmake` call, that is:

```
pi@raspberry:~/rtest/build $ ~/src/cmake-3.28.1/bin/cmake ../ -DBUILD_SSL=NO -DBUILD_TESTS=NO -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

... and then they somehow propagate to restbed, and `restbed/detail/http_impl.cpp.o` compiles without triggering the OpenSSL errors.

I should have probably also used cached CMake variables - but don't have the time to test that now ...

---

Well, it's a shame the question got closed, especially since [Using FetchContent_Declare together with CMAKE_ARGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62101576/using-fetchcontent-declare-together-with-cmake-args) does NOT answer this question (I don't have a question on how to use cmake args, but how to compile this project; but of course the moderators couldn't be bothered to read or understand the question in its entirety), but lucky that I've posted an answer in time, that I could edit.

Eventually, the reason *why* it does not compile, is in the log CMake reports:

```
-- Found ASIO include at: /home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/asio/asio/include
-- Found OpenSSL include at: /home/pi/code/BBS_OLA_Bridge/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include
-- Found OpenSSL library at: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.a
-- Found OpenSSL library at: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so
-- Found Crypto library at: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.a
-- Found Crypto library at: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so
```

Basically, on this system, I have this libssl-dev:

```
$ apt-show-versions libssl-dev
libssl-dev:armhf/stretch 1.1.0l-1~deb9u6 uptodate
```

... however, since FetchContent downloads all dependencies, *including* openSSL - and since the [restbed/cmake/Findopenssl.cmake](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/cmake/Findopenssl.cmake) prefers `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl`, I've ended up with a `/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include` as the include path, which includes newer code in `/home/pi/rtest/build/_deps/restbed-src/dependency/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h`, rather than the system one `/usr/include` (where `/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h` resides).

The `Findopenssl.cmake` tells us that the related `restbed` CMake variable is `ssl_INCLUDE` - so it turns out, the only fix needed is to add `set(ssl_INCLUDE "/usr/include")` in the main CMakeLists.txt here:

```cmake
# ...
FetchContent_Declare(
  restbed
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed
  GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
  GIT_TAG        0c99284 # Oct 3, 2022, latest in Jan 2024
)
set(ssl_INCLUDE "/usr/include")
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(restbed)
# ...
```

... and indeed, then the main project compiles fine, even if `cmake` for it is called with `-DBUILD_SSL=YES`.

Comment: "I don't have a question on how to use cmake args, but how to compile this project; but of course the moderators couldn't be bothered to read or understand the question in its entirety" - It is me who close your question as a duplicate. I am NOT a moderator: they have a diamond near the name. And I perfectly understand your question. You don't ask about "How to set parameters with FetchContent", but you provide the code with clear description of that aspect: "... the `set(restbed_BUILD_SSL OFF)` is my guess based on ...)". Your code **attempts** to set parameters, but does that incorrectly.

Comment: Please note, that discussion of closing should not be a part of the answer **post**. If you wonder why a question is closed as duplicate, you may ask that in the comments to the question. Moreover, if a question is closed in "single-handle" fashion, you may notify the closer with a usual `@name` syntax.